# Getting the current input by the user without user hitting enter

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Much like how google tries to auto-guess what is being input by the user. I am trying to figure out how much and what the user has typed before hitting enter. More difficult, I am trying to get this done through the console.

Although the input function does exist and is very easy to use.

```
var = input("Enter Name: ")
print(f'Hello, {var}')
```

I am trying to get this input 'dynamically'

Is this even possible?
I imagine the code would look like:

```
var = imaginary_input("Enter Name: ")
while not var.complete:
    current_input = var.get()
```

Is there a function that works similar to my 'imaginary_input' function?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

(I understand that this can easily be completed through a window with a textbox, but I would prefer this to be done over the console)

Comment: Have you looked at the `keyboard` module?  https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: I have, but that wouldn't work since the user could always click off the terminal, type something and my code would be confused.

Comment: If Python's `readline` module is available on your platform, you might be able to do something with its word completion feature.

Comment: @RushilS Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) should answer your question.

So for example if you're using windows:

```
import msvcrt

while (c := msvcrt.getch()) != b'\r':
    # Do something with read byte character
    print(c)
```